# How to create this type of touch friendly login button using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a touch device application. I have to create a Login button as shown in the image[image]

I have created the remaining part myself . I am not able to create the LOGIN button style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is is an example. You can easily modify the css to your need :

```css
.btn-login {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.btn-login:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p><a class="btn-login">LOGIN</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also added some hover effects to it. Here's the CSS for this Button,

```
.log-in {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #888;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.log-in:hover {
  background: #4f8be1;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Hope this will work for you, Here's Code on codepen.io

See the Pen [CSS Simple, Clean login button](https://codepen.io/vkubre/pen/vmLvbK/)  by vaibhav kubre ([@vkubre](http://codepen.io/vkubre)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0):

my friends, i guess you may looking something like those:

```
    // demos:
```

- 1. http://codepen.io/mehmetmert/pen/RNoJmj
- 2. http://codepen.io/clein/pen/xnmKL
- 3. http://codepen.io/andytran/pen/GpyKLM